# how to convert from one class to another in matlab

Tags: matlab, class

I have created a set of density values using the matlab function f=ksdensity(x) where x is a nx1 vector. Now this produces a result of class 'double'

```
{Columns 1 through 12

0.0001    0.0002    0.0003    0.0004    0.0006    0.0008    0.0012    0.0016    0.0022    0.0029    0.0038    0.0049
```

Columns 13 through 24

```
0.0062    0.0078    0.0095    0.0115    0.0136    0.0159    0.0183    0.0208    0.0233    0.0257    0.0281    0.0304
```

Columns 25 through 36

```
0.0327    0.0349    0.0370    0.0392    0.0414    0.0438    0.0463    0.0491    0.0521    0.0553    0.0586    0.0621
```

Columns 37 through 48

```
0.0656    0.0691    0.0723    0.0752    0.0776    0.0795    0.0808    0.0814    0.0814    0.0808    0.0796    0.0779
```

Columns 49 through 60

```
0.0758    0.0733    0.0707    0.0680    0.0652    0.0624    0.0597    0.0571    0.0547    0.0523    0.0501    0.0479
```

Columns 61 through 72

```
0.0459    0.0441    0.0423    0.0408    0.0393    0.0381    0.0370    0.0360    0.0352    0.0345    0.0338    0.0331
```

Columns 73 through 84

```
0.0324    0.0315    0.0305    0.0293    0.0279    0.0263    0.0244    0.0224    0.0203    0.0181    0.0158    0.0137
```

Columns 85 through 96

```
0.0116    0.0097    0.0079    0.0064    0.0051    0.0040    0.0030    0.0023    0.0017    0.0012    0.0009    0.0006
```

Columns 97 through 100

```
0.0004    0.0003    0.0002    0.0001}
```

But to further use this data I need to convert this into an array. How do I do that?

Comment: An array is not a *class*. It is a list of objects that each have a class. In your case, it looks like you already have an array **of** doubles. And looking at [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html#outputarg_f) it's definitely already an array/vector.

Answer (score 1):

The first output of [`ksdensity`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html#outputarg_f) is *already* an array/vector.

In MATLAB, an array is not a *class*. [It is a list of objects that each have the same class.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-numeric-arrays.html) Technically speaking, *all* MATLAB variables are arrays (any scalar is actually a 1 x 1 array).

So if we create an array:

```
x = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3];
```

The class is `double`

```
class(x)

    double
```

Or an array of integers

```
y = uint8([1,2,3]);

class(y)

    uint8
```

Or even if we get really crazy, we can have an array of `structs`

```
z = [struct(), struct(), struct()];

class(z)

    struct
```

So anything you want to do on your output (as an array) can already be done without any conversion.

Other datatypes (like [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)) may require some conversion to get then into a *numeric* array, but you're not dealing with that at this point. And you can always check their type with `iscell` or `class(data) == 'cell'`