# Prevent MATLAB from turning single element arrays into a non-array type

Tags: arrays, matlab, cells

I have a cell array, where each cell contains an array of strings. An example is as follows:

```
example = {{['a'], ['b']}, {['c']}}
```

However,

```
example{1}
```

returns a 1x2 cell array, whereas

```
example{2}
```

returns a cell, NOT a 1x1 cell array as expected. This single cell value is then not in the same format as the encapsulating example cell array, which breaks calculations further down the line.

How do I fix this? Ideally, I'd like to be able to have a 1x1 cell array and avoid any nasty special cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MATLAB, there is no difference between a scalar entity and a 1 x 1 array. The scalar is simply a 1 x 1 version of the array. There is no special array class, instead an array is simply [a list of objects that have the same class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html;jsessionid=b6ebda914829735d190a61313560).  This holds true regardless of whether it's a `double` array, a `char` array, a `struct` array, or in your case a `cell` array (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820543/how-to-convert-from-one-class-to-another-in-matlab/35820637#35820637)).

As such, `example{2}` *does* return a 1 x 1 cell array. You can test `example{2}` actually is a 1 x 1 cell by using [`class`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) , [`size`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html), [`iscell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/iscell.html), and/or [`whos`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html)

```
class(example{2})
%   cell

size(example{2})
%   1   1

iscell(example{2})
%   1

tmp = example{2};
whos('tmp')
%  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes
%
%  tmp       1x1               114  cell
```

Since it is a 1 x 1 cell array, the rest of your code should be able to handle it without any problems (assuming you wrote the rest of the code correctly).

Answer (score 2):

A one-element cell array is still a cell array of size 1x1. Observe:

```
>> class(example{1})
ans =
cell
>> class(example{2})
ans =
cell
>> size(example{1}) 
ans =
     1     2
>> size(example{2}) 
ans =
     1     1
```

You can either test separately if your array is of size 1x1 in particular further down your code, or, consider whether indexing the cell array by `()` syntax somehow is more beneficial for you, e.g.:

```
>> example(1)
ans = 
    {1x2 cell}
>> example(2)
ans = 
    {1x1 cell}
```